# window.innerWidth is giving different sizes depending on browser

Tags: html, dom, cross-browser

I have a problem where the JavaScript variable window.innerWidth is giving different sizes depending on browser. Firefox gives me `1847`, Opera `1364` and Chrome `1412` if I have them fullscreen. A few pixels I could understand but not this much.

So I did some tests and found that `500px` is not the same width in all those browsers... The most simple html would result in 3 different results:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 500px; background: red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Browse Comparison]

Any ideas why this could happen? I did of course made sure I did not zoom in any browser. There all set to 100%. If I measure the screenshot Firefox is showing the actual 500px.

Answer (score 0):

From [CSS: The Definitive Guide: Visual Presentation for the Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449393195) discussing about the absolute length units(in,cm,mm,q,pt,pc,px):

> These units are really useful only if the browser knows all the details of the screen on which your page is displayed, the printer you’re using, or whatever other user agent might apply. On a web browser, display is affected by the size of the screen and the resolution to which the screen is set—and there isn’t much that you, as the author, can do about these factors. You can only hope that, if nothing else, the measurements will be consistent in relation to each other